# What is the way to support persistent state with different clients without using MongoDB in Meteor + React?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Sorry for my English. I have an app build with Meteor + React. It has the following features:
The user click the button and starts the counter. When another user comes to site, or the same user in a new tab - they need to see working counter. I understand that I need to save counter state. I tried to use MongoDB and every second update the state of counter, but it worked wrong with delays. So, the key idea I want to know: what is the best way to support persistent state with different clients without using MongoDB. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install streams

```
meteor add fds:streams
```

And then use it like this

```
chatStream = new Meteor.Stream('chat');

if(Meteor.isClient) {
  sendTime = function(time) {
    chatStream.emit('time_tick', time);
    //Add your sync logic here
    console.log('me: ' + time);
  };

  chatStream.on('time_tick', function(time) {
    console.log('user: ' + time);
    //Add your sync logic here
  });
}
```

Read [how streams works](http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/how-streams-works.html) or [checkout some examples](http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/examples.html)

Credits: [meteor-streams docs](http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/)

Comment: This package doesn't exist.

Comment: I add this package, write code as in example and when I reload page or watch site in another tab, counter start working from beginning. Tabs are not synchronized.

Comment: What i posted was to get you to the right direction, you should add your sync logic  instead of just console logging